# BCP export sql query to csv issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bcp

I am trying to use the bcp command in sql to export a query result to a csv file. Although the stored procedure executes the file is never created and I receive these two results in SSMS:

[image]

Not sure what the No Column name result is from, and the second table result appears to be all the options available to the bcp command. If someone can enlighten me as to why this is happening and point me in the right direction to get the file created I would be grateful.

Note: the Select is just a placeholder until the file creation works.

opps the extra \ before the c: wasn't always there so it wasn't that

I did switch to this, but still get the same results as the image without and output file:

```
DECLARE @H VARCHAR(2) = 'HI'
exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT @H AS Place"
queryout 
"c:\drew.txt"
-c -T'
```

Comment: Try changing the pertinent bit to `"SELECT 0 AS ColumnNamePlaceHolder"` and see what you get :-)

Comment: `**\**c:\drew` isn't that one too many slashes?

Comment: Also, check your flags. They are case sensitive. At current your flags do not make any sense (`-c`=character type, you've not specified one. `-t`=field terminator, again you've not specified one).

Comment: The output is telling you that you're not using the correct BCP command format.  One problem that I can see is that you have no connection information in the BCP command, so it probably has no idea what SQL server and DB to connect to.

Comment: You should first get a working BCP command line working outside SQL (i.e. in a command prompt) then try putting it into xp_cmdshell. With regards to your second command, the BCP command doesn't know anything about the `@H` variable

Comment: I did as you suggested and got the bcp command working locally:       bcp "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM databaseName.dbo.table" 
queryout "\\serverName\C$\folder\here.csv" -c -t, -S serverName -T       That worked for creating the file on my server but I can't get it to work in my stored procedure and have tired other such combinations